# Como calcular similaridade (em percentual) entre strings em PHP?

Tags: php, padrão-de-texto

Gostaria de saber como calcular a similaridade, em percentual, entre duas *strings* com PHP?

Por exemplo:

- Eu tenho um presente pra vocês!
- Eu quero alguns presentes de vocês!

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma nativa do próprio PHP é essa:

```
$var_1 = 'Eu tenho um presente pra vocês!'; 
$var_2 = 'Eu quero alguns presentes de vocês!'; 

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percentual); 

echo $percentual; 
// 73.529411764706
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ac97ccb9a14cf093f4c7fe6580ed626dda1e855